# Flutter: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed without error

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

I have a flutter app in production and we are trying to migrate from flutter 1.x to 2.x. During the process, we are confronting weird errors building in ios. We were able to fix a big part of it by updating dependencies but we are still encountering this weird issue. The worst part is that it seems to be just warnings, so we are a bit lost. The full log can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/javib51/103957450970654431954b29797ea1fd):

```
    Failed to build iOS app
    Error output from Xcode build:
    ↳
        ** BUILD FAILED **
    
    
    Xcode's output:
    ↳
        ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:13:5: warning: 'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            UILocalNotification *_launchNotification;
            ^
        In module 'UIKit' imported from ../app/app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        @interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>
                   ^
        ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:293:4: warning: 'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        - (UILocalNotification *)buildStandardUILocalNotification:(NSDictionary *)arguments {
           ^
        In module 'UIKit' imported from ../app/app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        @interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>
                   ^
        ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:752:30: warning: 'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification*)notification {
                                     ^
        In module 'UIKit' imported from ../app/app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        @interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>
                   ^
        ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:182:64: warning: 'scheduledLocalNotifications' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter getPendingNotificationRequestsWithCompletionHandler:] [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            NSArray *notifications = [UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications;
                                                                       ^
        In module 'UIKit' imported from ../app/app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:242:68: note: 'scheduledLocalNotifications' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        @property(nullable,nonatomic,copy) NSArray<UILocalNotification *> *scheduledLocalNotifications API_DEPRECATED("Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter getPendingNotificationRequestsWithCompletionHandler:]", ios
 ....
        ../app/app/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/FIRStorageDownloadTask.m:171:23: warning: 'waitForCompletionWithTimeout:' is deprecated: Use XCTestExpectation instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            [weakSelf.fetcher waitForCompletionWithTimeout:0.001];
                              ^
        In module 'GTMSessionFetcher' imported from ../app/app/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/FIRStorageTask_Private.h:29:
        ../app/app/ios/Pods/GTMSessionFetcher/Source/GTMSessionFetcher.h:1164:5: note: 'waitForCompletionWithTimeout:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
            __deprecated_msg("Use XCTestExpectation instead");
            ^
        In module 'Foundation' imported from ../app/app/ios/Pods/FirebaseStorage/FirebaseStorage/Sources/Public/FirebaseStorage/FIRStorageDownloadTask.h:17:
        In module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
        In module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:200:48: note: expanded from macro '__deprecated_msg'
                #define __deprecated_msg(_msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__(_msg)))
                                                              ^
        1 warning generated.
        ../app/app/ios/Pods/FirebaseDynamicLinks/FirebaseDynamicLinks/Sources/FIRDLJavaScriptExecutor.m:158:12: warning: unused function 'processIsTranslated' [-Wunused-function]
        static int processIsTranslated() {
                   ^
        1 warning generated.
    
        Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
        note: Using new build system
        note: Building targets in parallel
        note: Planning build
        note: Analyzing workspace
        note: Constructing build description
        note: Build preparation complete
```

The Podfile is the following:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
       end
    end
  end
```

We are a bit stuck with this right now. Is there any idea of what may be going on? Did someone confront this same error?

### Update: 2021-07-19 - 1

Looking deeper, I got into [xcode_backend.sh](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d0a29dc10c2889904650b8fa6723417358539786/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh#L173) fails running a flutter command with exit code 1. The command is the following:

```
flutter assemble --no-version-check --output=<path>/app/app/build/ios/Debug-dev-iphoneos/ \
-dTargetPlatform=ios \
-dTargetFile=<path>/app/app/lib/main_dev.dart \
-dBuildMode=debug \
-dIosArchs=arm64 \
-dSdkRoot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk \
-dSplitDebugInfo= \
-dTreeShakeIcons=false \
-dTrackWidgetCreation=true \
-dDartObfuscation=false \
-dEnableBitcode= \
-dCodesignIdentity=xxxx \
--ExtraGenSnapshotOptions= \
--DartDefines=xx,xx \
--ExtraFrontEndOptions= \
debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix this issue. Its that Flutter 2.0 has some breaking changes in the ios side and really shitty default debugging capabilities in this sense. Make sure that the verbose is enabled in the xcode_backend.sh during the building([here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d0a29dc10c2889904650b8fa6723417358539786/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh#L174)).

More specific about my error, flutter assemble was returning this error:

```
Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '<path>/app/app/ios/Flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

It works just adding AppFrameworkInfo.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>en</string>
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
  <string>App</string>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
  <string>io.flutter.flutter.app</string>
  <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
  <string>6.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>App</string>
  <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
  <string>FMWK</string>
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>1.0</string>
  <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
  <string>????</string>
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
  <string>1.0</string>
  <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
  <string>8.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Anyhow, the recommended approach is to remove your ios folder (or move it to ios.old during the migration) and re-create it running `flutter create -i swift`.